# Nose JS express session receives new session for every http request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ajax, express-session

This question has been asked multiple times, but none of the solutions works for me. In node.js, I'm using express-session and connect-mongodb-session. My client is developed by using React.js. Both server and client run on localhost but on different ports, 8080 & 3000 respectively. Below is my code for server:

```
import cors from "cors";
import session from "express-session";
const MongoDBStore = require("connect-mongodb-session")(session);

const corsOptions   = {
    origin      : true,
    credentials : true,
    methods     : ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"]
};

const sessionStore = new MongoDBStore(
    {
        uri        : process.env.MONGO_CON,
        collection : "sessionStore"
    }, (error : any) => {
        if(error){
            console.info("MONGO SESSION ERROR");
            console.info(error.message);
        }
        console.info("SESSION STORE INITIALIZED");
    });

sessionStore.on("error", (error : any) => {
    if(error){
        console.info("ON SESSION STORE ERROR");
        console.info(error.message);
    }
    console.info("SESSION STORE IS ON");
});

const sessionProps : session.SessionOptions = {
    secret            : "secretKey",
    resave            : true,
    saveUninitialized : true,
    store             : sessionStore,
    cookie            : {
        secure   : false,
        httpOnly : false,
        sameSite : "none",
        domain   : "http://localhost:8080/",
        maxAge   : 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 // 1 day * 1 Week
    }
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(session(sessionProps));
```

In my React client, I am using the following module to send AJAX requests:

```
export const lats_ajax = (props : TypeAjax) => {
    const params : any = props.params;
    for(let key in params){
        if(!params.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
        const value = params[key];
        params[key] = (typeof value === "object" || Array.isArray(value))
                      ? JSON.stringify(value)
                      : value;
    }
    
    // Encode Keys & Data as URI String
    const encodedParams = Object.keys(params)
                                .map(key => `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(params[key])}`)
                                .join("&");
    
    // Create & Initialize New HTTP Request
    const httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.open(props.method || "post", props.url, true);
    httpRequest.withCredentials = true;
    httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    
    // If Next is Available, Call Next When Request is finished & Response is ready
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function(this : XMLHttpRequest){
        if(this.readyState === 4 && props.next)
            props.next({status : this.status, statusText : this.statusText, response : this.response}, props.carry);
    };
    
    // Send HTTP Request with Encoded Params
    httpRequest.send(encodedParams);
};
```

Everything works fine on Firefox, but on Edge and Chrome, for every Ajax request, the server receives a new session id. This issue seems only with the React or different port version because when I developed a vanilla js client and run on the same port with the server, the new session id issue doesn't occur at all. I checked the settings of all the browsers and finds nothing to rectify the issue, but still don't able to understand why the issue is occurring only for Edge and Chrome browsers, not with Firefox. Thanks!